# Can't emulate large screen size

Tags: android, android-emulator

I have a publicated app in Google Play for a year now.
A bug has been spotted, some of the layouts are showing not so well in really large screens like Samsung Galaxy S5's (1080x1920)

I tried to make an emulator with this screen size but my computer just loaded and loaded (black screen on emulator) and hours later nothing really happened.
(Pc: i7, 4GB RAM)

Could anybody suggest me a way to emulate a screen size like this? 
Sadly, i cannot have a real device like that.

Comment: try deactivating the checkbox "Use Host GPU" when starting the emulator

Comment: don't use the Google emulator it's really really really really really bad. I suggest you Genymotion (www.genymotion.com) as it works surprisingly well.

Comment: I've got a comparable configuration and this works.
How much RAM is set to be used by your emulator ? What OS are you using ? Is hardware acceleration enabled ? http://developer.android.com/tools/devices/emulator.html#vm-windows